# Pesquisa de conteúdo em mais de uma coluna (TTable)

Tags: banco-de-dados, array, table, delphi-6, paradox

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Delphi 6, que preciso realizar uma busca em mais de um campo em uma TTable, utilizando apenas um campo de busca.

Atualmente, a busca está sendo feita apenas em um campo procurando em apenas uma coluna:

```
procedure TfrmCadastroChamados.btnPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    tblChamados.Open;
    tblChamados.IndexFieldNames:= ('IdChamado');
    tblChamados.findkey([mskPesquisar.Text]);
end;
```

Mas preciso procurar o que foi digitado em "mskPesquisar"não só em IdChamado mas também nas outras colunas da tabela, ou seja, uma pesquisa robusta olhando todos os campos, e caso seja encontrado, retorne o resultado no meu DBGrid.

Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Obs: Estou utilizando TTable em Paradox.